# Select MongoDB documents where a field either does not exist, is null, or is false?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, database

Suppose I have a collection that contains the following documents:

```
{ "_id": 1, name: "Apple" }
{ "_id": 2, name: "Banana", "is_reported": null }
{ "_id": 3, name: "Cherry", "is_reported": false }
{ "_id": 4, name: "Kiwi",   "is_reported": true }
```

Is there a simpler query to select all documents where "is_reported" is in a falsy state; that is, either non-existent, null, or false?  That is, a query that selects Apple, Banana, and Cherry, but not Kiwi?

[According to the MongoDB FAQ](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/faq/developers/#faq-developers-query-for-nulls), `{ "is_reported": null }` will select documents where "is_reported" is either null or nonexistent, but it still doesn't select documents where "is_reported" is false.

Right now I have the following query, which works fine, but it just doesn't seem very elegant.  If there are multiple fields that I need to select on, it gets messy very fast.  Is there a better query that achieves the same end result?

```
db.fruits.find({ $or: [ { "is_reported": null }, { "is_reported": false } ] })
```

Answer (score 147, accepted):

You can do this with [`$in`](http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/query/in/#op._S_in):

```js
db.fruits.find({is_reported: {$in: [null, false]}})
```

returns:

```js
{
  "_id": 1,
  "name": "Apple"
}
{
  "_id": 2,
  "name": "Banana",
  "is_reported": null
}
{
  "_id": 3,
  "name": "Cherry",
  "is_reported": false
}
```

You could also flip things around logically and use `$ne` if you don't have any values besides `true` to exclude:

```js
db.fruits.find({is_reported: {$ne: true}})
```

Comment: Does null query documents where field does not exist?

Comment: @wbeange Yes, a `null` query value also matches docs where that field doesn't exist.

Comment: Upvote for `$ne`. It's underrated!